# merging json with python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have following code to merge values in my json:

```
from jsonmerge import merge

with open('env.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    result2 = merge("", data.get('default_attributes'))
    result3 = merge(result2, data.get('normal_attributes'))
    result4 = merge(result3, data.get('override_attributes'))
    result5 = merge(result4, data.get('force_override_attributes'))
    > print result4, result5
    result6 = merge(result5, data.get('automatic_attributes'))
    cookbook_versions = {"cookbook_versions" : data.get('cookbook_versions')}
    result7 = merge(result6, cookbook_versions)
```

Now when I print result4, result5 I get :

> result4 = {u'modmon': {u'env': u'dev'}, u'default': {u'env':
>   u'developmen-jq'}, u'paypal': {u'artifact': u'%5BINTEGRATION%5D'},
>   u'windows': {u'password': u'Pib1StheK1N5'}, u'task_sched':
>   {u'credentials': u'kX?rLQ4XN$q'}, u'seven_zip': {u'url':
>   u'https://.io/artifactory/djcm-zip-local/djcm/chef/paypal/7z1514-x64.msi'},
>   u'7-zip': {u'home': u'%SYSTEMDRIVE%\7-zip'}}
>
> result5 = None

which doesn't make sense to me as in result5 I'm merging result 4 which already has content in it then why does it come out null ?

Comment: I hope that this is a fake password...

Comment: yup removed it and is fake. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `data.get('force_override_attributes')` is `None` then `merge(result4, data.get('force_override_attributes'))` is `None`

```
>>> a = {"a":10}
>>> b = merge(a, None)
>>> print b 
    None
```

What you can do is:

```
result5 = merge(result4, data.get('force_override_attributes') or {})
```

So even if it is an `None` the value of result4 will be retained.

or another option is to reverse the order, this should also work:

```
result5 = merge(data.get('force_override_attributes'), result4)
```

Comment: why is that ? Shoudnt merge merge the two values and not overwrite non common values? any doc links to support this ?